# SQLite query with multiple arguments

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to query an SQLite table for a row which has the same day of the week between a start time and end time as follows:

```
    String whereClause = String.format("%s = '?' AND %s <= '?' %s > '?'",
            Shift.PROP_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK, Shift.PROP_START_TIME,
            Shift.PROP_END_TIME);
    String[] whereargs = new String[] { String.valueOf(dow), time, time };
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(whereClause, whereargs);
```

However I am getting the following Logcat error.

```
03-30 22:46:02.827: E/AndroidRuntime(11507): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "dayOfTheWeek": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: dayOfTheWeek = '?' AND startTime <= '?' endTime > '?'
```

I have added the single quote(') to surround the question mark(?). It is not working without the single quote also. I have added them since sql statement can be sensitive to having the quote or not. If I am on the wrong track, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the missing `AND`, you have put string delimiters around the parameter markers, which prevents them from being recognized as parameters.
`'?'` is just a string containing a question mark; for a parameter, use a plain `?`:

```java
String.format("%s = ? AND %s <= ? AND %s > ?", ...);
```

Furthermore, when using `rawQuery`, you have to write out the entire SQL query.
To use a where clause like you're trying to do, you'd need `query`:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query("MyTableName",
                         null,  // or column list
                         whereClause, whereargs,
                         null, null, null);
```

Comment: 03-31 12:24:35.797: E/AndroidRuntime(18720): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "dayOfTheWeek": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: dayOfTheWeek = ? AND startTime <= ? AND endTime > ?    still not working

Comment: of course ... how am I going to query without a tablename?! I still get `Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.` error because I have left over code using "'" from "%s = '?' AND %s <= '?' %s > '?'" to give feedback to Patashu. All fix now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`"%s = '?' AND %s <= '?' %s > '?'"`

forgot an AND between the second and third conditions

`"%s = '?' AND %s <= '?' AND %s > '?'"`

then test to see if it needs '' or not

Comment: it is still not working     03-31 12:29:38.487: E/AndroidRuntime(19174): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "dayOfTheWeek": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: dayOfTheWeek = '?' AND startTime <= '?' AND endTime > '?'